# What does meshgrid do in this plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to replicate the plot in [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_isolation_forest.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-isolation-forest-py) SKLearn example code with my own model. I don't quite understand what the following lines do, and how to modify them to my own model:

```
# plot the line, the samples, and the nearest vectors to the plane
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 50), np.linspace(-5, 5, 50))
Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]) #this line created a runtime error with my own input
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
```

What does meshgrid do (I've checked the official description but I couldn't understand it - can you explain with layman's terms)? OK it creates a coordinate matrix, but why do we need that? How do I need to set it up for my own data? If I only change the input in this code, it crashes with `IndexError: list index out of range` (line marked above).

Comment: We need to know how your data looks like. Can you please indicate the shape of your input arrays?

Comment: It is explained in the tutorial I linked. You can just use that example to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the snippet, the `X` and `Y` variables can take any value between -5 and 5. This range is divided in 50 steps, so you want evaluate `clf.decision_function` in a 50x50 grid to get `Z`. You want to have `Z[0][0] = clf.decision_function(-5, -5)`, `Z[-1][-1] = clf.decision_function(5, 5)`, etc. [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) generate arrays that help you achieve that. What you need is to have every possible pair of `X` and `Y` values. `xx` is an array with as many rows as `Y` values and as many columns as `X` values, and each row is just the list of possible values for `X`. Conversely, `yy` has the same dimensions but here each column is the list of possible `Y` values. So something like:

```
xx:

[[   0, ...,  50 ],
 [   0, ...,  50 ],
 ...,
 [   0, ...,  50 ]]

yy:

[[   0,   0, ...,   0 ],
 ...,
 [  50,  50, ...,  50 ]]
```

If you look closely, you will not that taking every pair of corresponding values from `xx` and `yy` will give you all the possible combinations of `X` and `Y` values. `clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])` will therefore evaluate `clf.decision_function` with a two-column matrix where every row is a different combination of `X` and `Y` values.

Finally, reshaping `Z` to the shape of `xx` (remember this is the same shape as `yy`, which is `<number of Y values> × <number of X values>` will give you a matrix such that `Z[i][j] = clf.decision_function(<X j-th value>, <Y i-th value>)`. No, I didn't get that wrong, the first dimension of `Z` refers to the `Y` value index and the second dimension to the `X` value index. This is because [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) emulates the behaviour of [`MATLAB's meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), and the rationale is that this function is very frequently used for plotting 2D functions, where the `X` is expected to be the horizontal axis and the `Y` the vertical axis, but when plotting a matrix we *also* expect to see the rows in the horizontal dimension and the columns in the vertical ones, so swapping axis at some point becomes necessary. [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) also supports an `indexing` optional parameter which can be set to `'ij'` to keep `X` in the first dimension and `Y` in the second, similarly to [`MATLAB's ndgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html).